# How to start new activity on button click event in custom adapter?

Tags: android

I am very new in Android, doing code using google only, plz help.

Here is my code from custom adapter, which is for custom view which is having list of text and buttons, on button click event i want to start new activity, like for example, if user press button which is in front of "Geometry" text, then new activity should get start, what should I pass to intent in above code:

```
     @Override
     public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

         btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(View v)
                     {
                         if(txtListChild.getText().toString()=="Geometry")
                         {
                             Toast.makeText(_context,   txtListChild.getText().toString(),
                                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                             **Intent i=new Intent();**
                             _context.startActivity(i);
                         }

                     }
                });

     return convertView;
   }
```

Comment: it would be better is you can move your click listener to your host (Fragment or activity) it would render a more flexible and readable code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `intent` like

```
  Intent i=new Intent(_context,secondActivity.class);
  _context.startActivity(i);
```

Remember you must register `secondActivity` in `manifest.xml`

and also you should change

```
 if(txtListChild.getText().toString()=="Geometry")
```

to

```
 if(txtListChild.getText().toString().equals("Geometry"))
```

always used .`equals()` method for `string` comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

-By passing context from activity to the adapter like
`Youadapter` obj=new `Youradapter`(Youactivity.this);
-In you adapter class set you Context con; 
-and using con.startactivity;

Answer (score 0):

> How to start new activity on button click event in custom adapter?

*First,* use `String.equals` for comparing strings:

```
if(txtListChild.getText().toString().equals("Geometry"))
```

*Second*, to start Activity using string class name use `Class.forName` to get class:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName(txtListChild.getText().toString());
Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),c);
```

And make sure all activities are declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**NOTE:** if `txtListChild.getText()` return Activity name then no need to use `if-else` just use `Class.forName` to get class and pass it as last parameter of Intent constructor  :